# How to make a field computed only if some condition is fulfilled in Odoo 8?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

Is there any way in Odoo 8 to create a field which is computed only if some condition is fulfilled, otherwise the user will be able to set its value?

**Example**

I have a model named `box`, which has a float field named `value`.

Imagine a box can have several boxes inside, each one which its own value.

So we have a one2many field named `child_ids` pointing to `box` and a many2one named `parent_id` pointig to box too.

Now I want the following behaviour: an user can set the `value` field of a box which has not any box inside (it means, `childs_ids` is *False*), but, if the box has at least one box inside (it means, `childs_ids` is NOT *False*), the `value` field must be computed and it will be the sum of its childs `value`.

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this behaviour?

I put my code, which is not working (the value of `value` is always being reset to 0):

```
class box(models.Model):
    _name='box'

    @api.one
    @api.depends('child_ids', 'child_ids.value')
    def _compute_value(self):
        if self.child_ids:
            self.value = sum(
                [child.value for child in self.child_ids])

    def _set_value(self):
        pass

    parent_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='box',
                                string='Parent Box')

    child_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name='box',
                                inverse_name='parent_id',
                                string='Boxes inside')

    value = fields.Float(
        string='Value',
        compute='_compute_value',
        inverse='_set_value',
        store=False,
        required=True,
        readonly=True,
        states={'draft':[('readonly',False)]},
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the model

```
computed_field = fields.Char(compute='comp', inverse='inv', store=True)
boolean_field = fields.Boolean()

@api.one
def comp(self):
    ...

@api.one
def inv(self):
    ...
```

in the view

```
<field name="boolean_field" />
<field name="computed_field" attrs="{'readonly': [('boolean_field','=',True)]}" />
```

edit:

now that your example is more clear, i'd say you should change the following:

set **value**'s *store* parameter to *True* instead of *False* and just remove the *inverse* which, in your case, you don't need.

then you need another 2 fields

```
value_manual = fields.Float()
manual = fields.Boolean(compute='_is_manual', default=True)

@api.one
@api.depends('child_ids')
def _is_manual(self):
    self.manual = len(self.child_ids) == 0
```

plus

```
@api.one
@api.depends('child_ids', 'child_ids.value')
def _compute_value(self):
    if self.child_ids:
        self.value = sum(
            [child.value for child in self.child_ids])
    else:
        self.value = self.value_manual
```

in the view:

```
<field name="manual" invisible="1" />
<field name="value" attrs="{'invisible': [('manual','=',True)]}" />
<field name="value_manual" attrs="{'invisible': [('manual','=',False)]}" />
```

There could be another solution that avoid this double field, maybe using the inverse, but I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you @Alessandro, now I know that I have to use the inverse parameter, but the example I always find wherever I look is the `get_document`-`set_document` one, which is not much understandable. The best one I found is in `partner_street_number` module, but even so, I cannot understand what I have to write in `inv` method (the purpose is do nothing if `boolean_field` is *False*, to preserve the value the user set).

Comment: it depends, even nothing if you need no particular operations besides the one of storing the value. in this case you could skip the *inverse* parameter

Comment: Hi @Alessandro, I have updated my question with a better example and added code to make it more understandable. Do I still have to use `inverse` parameter? Can you help me with the `inverse` method, please?

Comment: Hi, I tried to improve my solution based on your example

Comment: Thank you very much @Alessandro for your efforts. This is a great workaround.

Comment: I have just checked that this solution is not working properly. It seemed to work great, with parent and children, but now I have created a grandparent, and when the children are updated, the parents are updated too, but not the grandparents. I have posted this problem on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408330/how-to-deal-with-recursion-and-api-depends-in-odoo-8

Comment: @forvas I'm facing the same problem.I'm creating a module which has a functionality of calculating the results that a student get in different subjects.Those fields are filled by the user and when he select a special subject ( which the average of other ones) the field must be computed automatically.I come implement all this but the computed field get is updated only when the user save data, which means the compute function get data only from database not immediately from the fields of the form.Can you give me a clear idea how to overcome or snippet of code please?

Comment: May be you prefer to use a method which updates the fields with the decorator `@api.onchange` in this case?

Comment: Have you guys figured it out? I was able to make it work but there are data duplications since I'm trying to change inherited fields...